# Android Listview Adapter with scroll

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview adapter as follows:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<ApplicationPojo> applicationList = null;
    private Activity activity;
    private Bitmap logoImg;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private String logoName;
    //private String fileName;
    private PackageManager pm;
    private boolean isAppInstalled;


    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ApplicationPojo> applicationList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.activity = (Activity)mContext;
        this.applicationList = applicationList;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return applicationList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationPojo getItem(int position) {
        return applicationList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        if (view == null)
        {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleapp, null);

            holder.appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.appName);
            holder.developer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.developer);
            holder.rate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rateApp);
            holder.updateBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.updateApp);
            holder.installBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.install);
            holder.openInstalledApp = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.openInstalledApp);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        try
        {
            final View finalView = view;

            holder.logo = (ImageView) finalView.findViewById(R.id.appLogo);
            logoName = applicationList.get(position).getLogo();

            Picasso.with(activity)
                    .load(IPClass.SERVERIP + logoName)
                    .into(holder.logo);


            if(!appInstalled(applicationList.get(position).getFileName().substring(0, applicationList.get(position).getFileName().length() - 4)))
            {
                if(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/appsaraai/" + applicationList.get(position).getFileName()).exists())
                {

                    holder.installBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.installBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/appsaraai/" + applicationList.get(position).getFileName())), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                            activity.startActivity(intent);

                            for (int i = 0; i < DownloadLists.list.size(); i++) {

                                if (DownloadLists.list.get(i).getName().equals(applicationList.get(position).getName()));
                                {
                                    DownloadLists.list.remove(i);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                else
                {
                    holder.updateBtn.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                    holder.updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0)
                        {
                            String id = applicationList.get(position).getId();
                            int category = applicationList.get(position).getCategory();

                            Intent rec1Intent = new Intent(activity,AppView.class);
                            activity.startActivity(rec1Intent);

                            AppView appView = new AppView();
                            appView.setParameters(id,category);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            else
            {
                holder.updateBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.openInstalledApp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.openInstalledApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Context ctx = mContext;
                        Intent mIntent = ctx.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(applicationList.get(position).getFileName());
                        String mainActivity = mIntent.getComponent().getClassName();
                        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
                        intent.setClassName(applicationList.get(position).getFileName(), mainActivity);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }

            holder.appName.setText(applicationList.get(position).getName());
            holder.developer.setText(applicationList.get(position).getDeveloper());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("Adapter Exception", ex.toString());
        }
        return view;
    }

    public boolean appInstalled(String checkApp)
    {
        pm = activity.getPackageManager();

        try
        {
            pm.getPackageInfo(checkApp, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            isAppInstalled = true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            isAppInstalled = false;
        }

        return isAppInstalled;
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView logo;
        TextView appName;
        TextView developer;
        TextView rate;
        ImageView updateBtn;
        ImageView installBtn;
        ImageView openInstalledApp;

    }

}
```

the list contains list of applications. here I check if an application is installed in the device so on that item an open button is displayed and if the application is not installed download button is displayed so the user can download it. every thing works fine until i scroll the list. When i scroll the list the buttons overlap with each other any idea!!

Comment: Can you post your xml layout? and maybe a screenshot will picture better the issue.

Comment: the getItemId function seems useless, what is it used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not setVisibility(GONE) for holder.openInstalledApp if app not installed:

## Try this. Edited for your code:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<ApplicationPojo> applicationList = null;
private Activity activity;
private Bitmap logoImg;
private ViewHolder holder;
private String logoName;
//private String fileName;
private PackageManager pm;
private boolean isAppInstalled;


public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ApplicationPojo> applicationList) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.activity = (Activity)mContext;
    this.applicationList = applicationList;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return applicationList.size();
}

@Override
public ApplicationPojo getItem(int position) {
    return applicationList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{

    if (view == null)
    {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleapp, null);

        holder.appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.appName);
        holder.developer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.developer);
        holder.rate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rateApp);
        holder.updateBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.updateApp);
        holder.installBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.install);
        holder.openInstalledApp = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.openInstalledApp);

        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    try
    {
        final View finalView = view;

        holder.logo = (ImageView) finalView.findViewById(R.id.appLogo);
        logoName = applicationList.get(position).getLogo();

        Picasso.with(activity)
                .load(IPClass.SERVERIP + logoName)
                .into(holder.logo);


        if(!appInstalled(applicationList.get(position).getFileName().substring(0, applicationList.get(position).getFileName().length() - 4)))
        {
            //----------My code -----------
            //If app not installed holder.openInstalledApp
            //must be not visible

            holder.openInstalledApp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //---------------------

            if(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/appsaraai/" + applicationList.get(position).getFileName()).exists())
            {

                //----------My code -----------
                //If app not must be installed (not updated)
                //holder.updateBtn must be not visible
                holder.updateBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //---------------------

                holder.installBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.installBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/appsaraai/" + applicationList.get(position).getFileName())), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        activity.startActivity(intent);

                        for (int i = 0; i < DownloadLists.list.size(); i++) {

                            if (DownloadLists.list.get(i).getName().equals(applicationList.get(position).getName()));
                            {
                                DownloadLists.list.remove(i);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            else
            {

                //----------My code -----------
                //If app not must be updated
                //holder.updateBtn must be not visible

                holder.installBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //---------- ----------

                holder.updateBtn.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                holder.updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0)
                    {
                        String id = applicationList.get(position).getId();
                        int category = applicationList.get(position).getCategory();

                        Intent rec1Intent = new Intent(activity,AppView.class);
                        activity.startActivity(rec1Intent);

                        AppView appView = new AppView();
                        appView.setParameters(id,category);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        else
        {

            //----------My code -----------
            //If app installed and updated
            //buttons what no needed must be not visible

            holder.installBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.updateBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //---------------------

            holder.openInstalledApp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.openInstalledApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Context ctx = mContext;
                    Intent mIntent = ctx.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(applicationList.get(position).getFileName());
                    String mainActivity = mIntent.getComponent().getClassName();
                    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
                    intent.setClassName(applicationList.get(position).getFileName(), mainActivity);
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        holder.appName.setText(applicationList.get(position).getName());
        holder.developer.setText(applicationList.get(position).getDeveloper());

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.d("Adapter Exception", ex.toString());
    }
    return view;
}

public boolean appInstalled(String checkApp)
{
    pm = activity.getPackageManager();

    try
    {
        pm.getPackageInfo(checkApp, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        isAppInstalled = true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        isAppInstalled = false;
    }

    return isAppInstalled;
}

public class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView logo;
    TextView appName;
    TextView developer;
    TextView rate;
    ImageView updateBtn;
    ImageView installBtn;
    ImageView openInstalledApp;

}

}
```

Remember convertView save it previous state and need to be changed for each item.

Comment: thanks dear for reply! But how to change the view any clue?

Comment: you are great dear!! Thanks that works perfectly! There is now a problem i get NullPointer Exception at : String mainActivity = mIntent.getComponent().getClassName(); although I have used it in other places to open applications but here it is not working!!!